# /# added to website URL

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have made a mobile site using jquery mobile 1.3.1. The problem is that when I try to go from the front page View Menu I get /# in the URL as in tironci.dyndns.org/freddys/#/menu.html . I have no idea what is causing this. When I go from menu.html back to index.html the a # is added to the url. In desktop you cannot see the /# but on an ipad you can see it. If the page is refreshed than the menu buttons work.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Freddy's Place</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="styles/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/f.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="f">
<div  id="page2">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" data-transition="pop" data-theme="f" href="menu.html">
            View Our Menu
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

menu.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Freddy's Place</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() { 
  $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true; 
}); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".year").text( (new Date).getFullYear() );
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="styles/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/f.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="f">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="f" data-backbtn="false">
      <h1>Freddy's Place <br>Breakfast and Lunch</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="f" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#page2">Eggs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page3">Pancakes / French Toast</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page4">Omelettes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page5">Salads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page6">Muffins and Bagels</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page7">Plates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page8">Cereals / Oatmeal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page9">Sandwiches / Clubs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page10">Grilled Sandwiches</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page11">Open Face Sandwiches</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page12">Salad Rolls</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page13">Pasta</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page14">Soups</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page15">Side Orders</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="f">
      <h4>Freddy's Place &copy; <span class="year"></span></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="f">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="f"> <a href="#page" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-rel="home">Home</a>
      <h1>Eggs</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">


      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
        <li>One Egg, any style  <span class="price">$3.75</span></li>                   
        <li>One Egg, any style <br> w/ Bacon, Ham or Sausage <span class="price">$4.50</span></li>
        <li>Two Eggs, any style <span class="price">$4.50</span></li>
        <li>Two Eggs, any style <br> w/ Bacon, Ham or Sausage <span class="price">$4.95</span></li>
        <li>Two Eggs, any style <br> w/ Sirloin Tips <span class="price">$7.75</span></li>
        <li>Two Eggs, any style <br> w/ Corned Beef Hash <span class="price">$6.95</span></li>
        <li >Hungry Man Special <span class="price">$7.50</span>       
          <p class="hungry">Three Eggs (any style) w/ Two Bacon, <br>Two Sausages, Two Pancakes, Coffee <br> No Splits, No Substitutions</p>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="f">
      <h4>Freddy's Place &copy; <span class="year"></span></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have this `$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;` and in header you've put `data-backbtn="false"`? Anyway, jQueryMobile uses AJAX to load pages, this is why you see hash-tag. You can change between pages using `$.mobile.changePage()` without changing url hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: jQuery mobile is causing this and there is no real way around it.

Long answer: jQuery mobile, in order to support page transitions (slides, fade in/out) on links, converts every single one of your link to a hashtag-based reference (if your site started as `dir/page.html` and you are trying to get `dir/my/new.html`, the real link to it will be `dir/page.html#/my/new.html`. This is a feature, and not a bug. The feature in question is the ability to bookmark specific page by hashtag rather than by full page. Unless other parts of your script use `window.location.hash` for anything, there is no reason to disable it.

As far as I know, there is no way to disable this (Nor should you ever want to, transitions are pretty much the number 2 reason to use jQuery mobile, number 1 being touch event synthesis).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Very helpful. The problem I am having is: when I am at index.html and I click on View our menu it takes me to the menu but the user is not able to use the menu unless the page is refreshed. How do I fix that?

Comment: @tironci: That one is trivial - put your page2, page3... inside the div with `data-role="content"` so it actually gets loaded and not silently dropped as it currently is.

Comment: When I put `<div data-role="content" id="page1"></d>` in the menu.html the pages do not load at all. Sorry for the trivial questions but I am new to jQuery.

Comment: @tironci: `<div data-role='page' id='page1'>` INSIDE the data-role='content' you already have.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in my situation was to add `rel="external"` to the `<a>` tag.